# Restful web service required but need to redirect into SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, rest, httphandler

I am faced with the following situation and I do not know how to handle it. Any advice or ideas are welcome.

Requirements:

1. Provide a restful web service that handles a GET with parameters.
2. Redirect the user to a SharePoint 2007 login page with those parameters still available.

What I have:

1. A restful web service that provides the needed end point (written in C# and hosted on IIS 7.5)
2. SharePoint site already setup

I am at a loss of how to handle this properly and since the requirement for the restful end point is not mine, I can't change that part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for. What do you want to have happen on the login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was not a clear question but I did find the answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/d6b02afd-47c9-4646-96ec-90d7f6d3a285

The main problem I was having was to redirect from a web service to another location. The first answer for the question at the above link worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much help i can offer, but since no one has aswered I will give you a start.

My application has a Rest web service and below is a method that returns an object called a SharepointRecommendation (a C# class, you can have your method return anything or void)

```
  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "SharepointRecommendations?clientid={clientID}&userid={userID}&messageid={messageID}&maxsharepointlinks={countSharepointLinks}")]
        public SharepointRecommendation GetSharepointRecommendations(int clientID, int userID, int messageID, int countSharepointLinks)
        {
           ....
```

From what I have read the uri for the method should not include the verb Get, but the method should.

Now as to the Response.Redirect I have never tried that with a Web Method, but if it works in your method Response.Redirect([address]?username=[UserName]&passsword=[Password]);

I think the Web Method might have to be a void (not return anything) so the request passes through.

Comment: Thanks for this information although I didn't use it exactly, returning void in the WebMethod was a key element in making my solution work.